# Eating an Egg Whole

Tags: halacha, minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mourning-aveilus, eggs

Is there a basis for this custom that one may not bite into an egg which is still whole, but must be first cut or broken in two, unless it's a time of mourning (aveilut) and only then the egg is bitten into whole? 
It seems some Sephardim are concerned for it, but don't know if there is any basis in halacha.

Comment: Interesting. I’m gonna guess B - Sephardim are concerned by it as they are with other things related to eggs/*aveilut* (e.g. if you need an egg from your neighbor give them sugar).